# JavaFX application on retina Windows 7 (bootcamp)

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a JavaFX application. This is how it looks in my retina and non-retina iMac:

[image]

And this is how it looks in my retina Windows 7 (bootcamp):

[image]

First of all, it looks smaller. Next, everything is wrongly positioned.

What's up with this? I developed with Java 8 and running on Java 1.8 SE.

Comment: I have the same issue. Didn't yet find a solution for it. There is a simillar problem when you open a JavaFX app on a computer you are connected to using remote desktop.

Comment: Are you making use of a layout manager?

Comment: @MadProgrammer if you mean creating the scene with scene builder then yeah. If you mean using stuff like flow panes and such no.

Comment: It's possible that the components are fixed positioned and not taking into account the differences between font metrics. Probably better to provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses